# ionic3 custom style with scss

Tags: css, sass, ionic3

app.scss

```
.background {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

The code above doesn't work in my ionic project, but if I change it to the following formats, it works.

```
[background] {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

In my view, `.` means style class. And I can use it like the following

```
<ion-content background></ion-content>
```

What does `[]` mean?

Is there anything wrong in my project?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_attr_contain.asp

Comment: This is not specifically related to ionic or sass more to HTML and CSS btw.

Comment: @muuvmuuv You are right, I make some mistakes about angular4.

Comment: @Jatin Devani Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets `[]` in css mean you accessing an attribute therefor `background` is correct as it points to any HTML-tag element which has an `background` attribute. If you want to use the dot `.` you need to add a class the element `class="classname"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 <ion-content class="background"></ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }
```